# What is 'draws'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> My draws are like a reservoir permanently. I take them off and you
>   hear splish splash.

In hot day, old man said that.
what is draws? what is the meaning of sentence...?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't "drawers?"

Comment: Oh, if that's drawers, I can understand meaning. Maybe scripter makes mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I am correct and the correct word is "drawers," this seems to be talking about an old man sweating a lot on a hot day who removes his "drawers" or underwear, and a great amount of sweat is released, to point of creating a noise like water. The word "permanently" would seem to be used incorrectly here, but it could be an example of very informal speech (not very confident about this).